# Python (Flask) with Google App Engine. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

I am trying to deploy a web-app to Google App Engine using Python and Flask. 
When I check my app on a localhost, it's running perfectly but when I deploy it and go to the link generated by GAE, I get a server 500 error.

This is what I see in the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/j~trial1-ak/20190123t212940.415607737396553406/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
  File "/base/data/home/apps/j~trial1-ak/20190123t212940.415607737396553406/lib/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "/base/data/home/apps/j~trial1-ak/20190123t212940.415607737396553406/lib/jinja2/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from jinja2.bccache import BytecodeCache, FileSystemBytecodeCache, \
  File "/base/data/home/apps/j~trial1-ak/20190123t212940.415607737396553406/lib/jinja2/bccache.py", line 24, in <module>
    import fnmatch
  File "/base/data/home/apps/j~trial1-ak/20190123t212940.415607737396553406/lib/fnmatch.py", line 38, in <module>
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=256, typed=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

The list of packages I install for the app are:

```
Flask==0.12.3
click==6.7
gunicorn==19.7.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.13.0
Werkzeug==0.12.1
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lru_cache` was introduced in Python 3.2. Maybe you are running Python 2.7 on the server?

Comment: Can you confirm if you're deploying this to GAE 1st generation (Python 2.7) or GAE 2nd generation (Python 3.7)?